# Spring application hangs or waits for a long time between request

Tags: spring, spring-security, websphere

We have spring 3.2 application which runs fine on our local under tomcat 7.1, but when I install on the websphere server in QA it hangs or waits for along time between the requests. When the application starts to respond back I don't see any error. This is the debug statements I see before I see above behavior

```
[10/1/14 17:25:40:385 EDT] 000000ba SystemOut     O 17:25:40.384 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
[10/1/14 17:25:40:386 EDT] 000000ba SystemOut     O 17:25:40.386 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
[10/1/14 17:25:40:386 EDT] 000000ba SystemOut     O 17:25:40.386 [WebContainer : 0] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

There is no deadlocks on the server, there is no memory issue or thread locking on the websphere side. Here is the security config for spring

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<security:http use-expressions="true"
               entry-point-ref="loginEntryPoint">

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/vcm/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/landing/menu/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/support/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loginError" access="permitAll"/>


    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/loginError"/>
    <security:custom-filter ref="learningAuthenticationFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>
    <security:logout  logout-url="/logout"
                      delete-cookies="ES,JSESSIONID,olsUserData,XServer"
                      success-handler-ref="learningLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

</security:http>


<bean id="learningLogoutSuccessHandler"
      class="com.mbusa.learn.security.LearningLogoutSuccessHandler">

</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="learningAuthenticationProvider"/>
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="learningAuthenticationService"           class="com.mbusa.learn.security.LearningAuthenticationServiceImpl">
</bean>

<bean id="learningAuthenticationProvider"
      class="com.mbusa.learn.security.LearningAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="learningAuthenticationService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="learningAuthenticationFilter" class="com.mbusa.learn.security.LearningAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="usernameParameter" value="j_username"/>
    <property name="passwordParameter" value="j_password"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/loginError"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="loginEntryPoint"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <constructor-arg value="/login/form"/>
</bean>
```

Is there any

Comment: If you're going to post debug logs, it's better to post them as quoted text (start each line with `>`) or as code (indent it by four spaces or highlight the text and use command-k) - it makes it much easier for other users to read your code and to help you out. You can edit your post using the `edit` link. You've also left the last sentence of your post unfinished.

Comment: This sounds like it should be looked at by someone with strong websphere background, since as per your question on Tomcat it operates fine but Websphere causes lag. It may be Websphere settings/monitoring/resourcing that is causing this, and someone with that background can assist you. I've added the tag for your benefit.